# Authenticate Firebase JWT token on server running NGINX + Node.JS

Tags: node.js, nginx, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication

I have a server hosting an NGINX front-end and a Node.JS back-end.
Scenario: The server needs to pass each request containing the JWT token to the Node.JS back-end which will validate the token using the Firebase SDK and if the token authenticates then it should pass the flow back to NGINX which should continue with the reverse proxy and route accordingly.

So far I have managed to set up the NGINX as a reverse-proxy which works effectively. I am confused as to how to pass the token to nginx for authentication and back to nginx to continue with the reverse proxy if verified.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx, but I believe the [Verify ID Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) could help with authenticating firebase tokens in web services

Comment: I am aware of the token required and I am able to authenticate it using the Firebase Admin SDK in a Node.Js app.
What I want is the Node.Js app to pass the flow back to the nginx if the token authenticates.
I know the way to do that is to use redirect in the http header but I'm not sure how to go about doing that

Comment: Is it possible to validate the token on nginx only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
I've created a public repository on GitHub; feel free to use it or fork and improve.

[Fire-Guard-Proxy](https://github.com/saadzafar/fire-guard-proxy/)